# anyone know this extension name: which show your name while typing on vscode highlight the "name upon or above the cursor"

Tags: visual-studio-code

Which vscode extension for showing on cursor your name while typing.

https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxtEBoG9wqTeRVQ85dfXozrYFSfGijx-Ua

i want to know the name of extension.

pls anyone tell me the name of it or link.

Comment: Looks like [Live Share](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MS-vsliveshare.vsliveshare)

Answer (score 0):

It's [`MS-vsliveshare.vsliveshare`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MS-vsliveshare.vsliveshare). The video you linked shows two people editing together in a Live Share session, and you can see that the person showing their screen has Live Share installed because of the Live Share icon on their left menu.